# Extended routing in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently migrating an old website from ASP.NET with `.htaccess` to ASP.NET Core 2 and I am facing some problems with the routing. This is a large website with almost 30 links and I have to keep the URL structure with the old one. So I tried extending the `Startup` class's `app.UseMvc(route)` function.

Here is my code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes => new CustomRouting("mydomain.com",app).GetRouts());
    }
}
```

and here are my other classes:

```
public class CustomRouting
{
    string domain;
    IApplicationBuilder app;

    public CustomRouting(string domain, IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.app = app;
    }

    public IRouteBuilder GetRouts()
    {
        IRouteBuilder route = new RouteBuilder(app);
        switch(domain)
        {
            case "mydomain.com":
                route = new DeRouting(app).GetRoutes();
                break;
            default:
                route = new DeRouting(app).GetRoutes();
                break;
        }
        return route;
    }
}

public class DeRouting
{
    IApplicationBuilder app;
    public DeRouting(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public IRouteBuilder GetRoutes()
    {
        IRouteBuilder routes = new RouteBuilder(app);
        routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //here should come more
        return routes;
    }
}
```

Currently I get the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: 'A default
>   handler must be set on the IRouteBuilder.'

How could I create a route collection for these rules? There will be more types of these url which will handle multiple domains.

Comment: Does the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing) help?

Comment: *“a large website with almost 30 links”* – That does not really make it large… Anyway, can you actually *show* some of the routes you want to map? It’s difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve when you’re just delegating the route construction to other components until you basically don’t do anything special.

Comment: I would like to define my routes outside the Startup class, not to hardcode it there. That's what I cannot achieve.

Comment: @Coder Why don't you fix the problem that the error is telling you about then? The documentation I already linked has an example that seems to fulfil the requirements.

Comment: I didn't find anything to my problem. The documentation shows you how to use a basic routing inside the Startup.cs, not how to extend it...

Comment: Create a `RouteHandler` and pass it to `RouteBuilder` as per the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomRouting
{
    string domain;
    IApplicationBuilder app;
    IRouteBuilder routeBuilder;

    public CustomRouting(string domain, IApplicationBuilder app, IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        this.domain = domain;
        this.app = app;
        this.routeBuilder = routes;
    }

    public IRouteBuilder GetRouts()
    {
        switch(domain)
        {
            case "mydomain.com":
                route = new DeRouting(app, routeBuilder).GetRoutes();
                break;
            default:
                route = new DeRouting(app, routeBuilder).GetRoutes();
                break;
        }

        return route;
    }
}

public class DeRouting
{
    IApplicationBuilder app;
    IRouteBuilder routeBuilder;

    public DeRouting(IApplicationBuilder app, IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        this.app = app;
        this.routeBuilder = routes;
    }

    public IRouteBuilder GetRoutes()
    {
        routeBuilder.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //here should come more
        return routes;
    }
}

// StartUp.cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    new RouteManager(app,routes).GetRoutes();
});
```